# DJANGO - how to retrieve picture from database(sqlite) to show it on html

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have loaded the pictures to database(sqlite) and now, how to get that photo in html, can you guys tell me the steps to get there, thanks in advance

I want to grab the picture from database and show it in the html.

Comment: do you want to show uploaded image in html?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

Comment: yes @ManojTolagekar

Answer (score 0):

To show uploaded images in template:

In html file:

```
<img src="/media/{{image}}" /> #image is a model field name.
```

This is the way you can view uploaded image in template.

Answer (score 0):

Your images are stored in your static files folder and not directly in the database. I assume you are using an `ImageField` to store the image in your model. Something like this:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="static/images/", null=True, blank=True)
```

If that's the case, in order to display it in one of your templates what you have to do is refer to the image url:

```
<img src="{{ mymodel.url }}" />
```